# What is this white stuff under the leaves of my fruit trees and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: fruit-trees, pest-control

i took this picture like thirty mins ago off of one of many fruit trees I own. I also would like to get rid of what ever it is so it doesn't affect the fruit that is growing.[image]

Comment: It's mealybug. We have q/a on these on the site. Start looking [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=mealy) for lots of questions and answers. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

Yup, Stephie is correct.  This will not hurt the fruit per se.  These guys suck up calories from the leaves. Depending on the size of your trees, if less than 8-10 feet, spraying with NEEM (at night please) would work very well.  Get UNDER the leaves.  How many trees and how large are affected by these guys?  If larger trees and more of them, I'd hire a professional arborist to spray NEEM.  They might suggest a yearly dormant oil treatment if this continues to be a problem.  Spraying with water regularly would help control.  Using a pretty stiff pressure but not a pressure washer or too hard of a spray that would damage leaves. They can also guide you with pruning which is pretty important for health of your tree (s) and better fruit.  Also  ask about proper fertilizing and watering.  Be worth the expense.